# Says "SD card not inserted" when it is

Tags: storage, internal-sd

I just got a BLU Energy 2 phone and I love it. The only problem I have is that it's not reading the 64gb sd card that I just bought for it. I made sure the software was up to date, rebooted it multiple times with the sd card in it/without the sd card in it, connected it to my computer to see if there would be a file for it. I don't know what else I can do other than get a new sd card but I don't want to buy another new sd card and find out that's not the problem.